# Can I deploy a Vue Cli app to act as a dependency for another project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

My team and I have built out the frontend of an application which is due to be handed over to a backend team that will integrate the components we created in to their own Vue Cli app.

We felt it would be "cleaner" to somehow setup the Vue Cli project we have as some kind of dependency to their own Vue Cli app instead of their team tearing our components out manually (we want a single-source of truth). Is this at all possible?

I had a look at build targets in Vue Cli but it feels like the wrong approach for us: 
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html

i.e. `vue-cli-service build --target lib`

Ideally, we want them to be able to import components directly from our project on-demand and not as one single/bundled JavaScript file as Vue's `--target lib` seems to produce.

Any guidance on the best approach for this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are they just Vue component files? [example user.vue]. _on-demand_ as in lazy loading the components? It sounds like what you want is to have a library of components similar to how in Vue you'd download an NPM UI library and use it example *Vuetify* https://vuetifyjs.com/en/. If that all you're doing might as well make it a private NPM package and have them install it into their project.

Comment: I asked a similar question in the vuejs forum. Maybe it can help you: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/create-custom-plugin-using-vue-cli-3/42810